# Change licence username of PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I'm on Ubuntu and I want to change my PhpStorm username, how can I do that?
I've tried adding `Duser.name = mynewname` in phpstorm64.vmoptions.

Comment: Change where (where it displays that you wish to change it)?

Comment: Which kind of "username" are you talking about? Have you tried checking the documentation, or opening a support ticket?

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to change anything related to the license manually.
If you need to change the licensee name or email, you should contact JetBrains Sales team at https://sales.jetbrains.com/hc/en-gb/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66372 and ask them to do this.